# No Stage in Designer 2013

Tags: workflow

I was trying to make workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013 and when I choose list workflow, give name and ok.. and appears windows with a name Step 1.. no Stage no such thing.. and I cannot make right action to Stage, because I see no stage, just Step 1? What is wrong with Sharepoint Designer 2013?

Comment: While you created workflow, did you check which platform it was targeting? if its 2010 then I guess you will not get any stages.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the List Workflow in SharePoint designer you need to give the name and select the **Platform Type** dropdown. This will contains SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013.
Select the SharePoint 2013 platform type to get the stages and new features like loop, call http service etc.